# Skip few lines during writing to file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, scripting

I am using fileinput.FileInput to get read lines from a file.

```
for line in fileinput.FileInput("abc.txt",inplace=1):
    if matching_string in line:
        #print few lines
    print line,
```

For example, abc.txt is

```
Hello
World
This is
Python
Script
Bye
```

And matching_string is "This".
I want the output "abc.txt" as:

```
Hello
World
File changed
C++
Script
Bye
```

I need to modify some lines in between and the count of number of lines to skip is not fixed. Sometimes, I may have to skip 2 lines as in above example, sometimes only 1 or more lines.

Comment: `print line,` is not valid Python 3.x syntax, it should be `print(line)`

Answer (score 0):

Assign the `fileinput` object to a variable. Then you can use `next()` to read a line inside the loop body.

```
with fileinput.FileInput("abc.txt",inplace=1) as f:
    for line in f:
        if matching_string in line:
            #print few lines
            next(f) # skip over the next input line
        print(line)
```